# Limit max number of parallel processes in Optuna

Tags: hyperparameters, optuna

How to limit the max number of parallel processes when running hyper-parameter search in Optuna?

Answer (score 1):

The number of parallel processes is equivalent to the number of the running process.

For example, suppose `foo.py` contains an optimization code based on optuna. Then when we run `foo.py` twice, the number of parallel processes is `2`.

```sh
python foo.py  # 1st process
python foo.py  # 2nd process
```

For more details, please see [this tutorial page](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/10_key_features/004_distributed.html#share-the-study-among-multiple-nodes-and-processes).

Comment: The poster of the question was asking about capping the CPU utilization when using Optuna. This answer does not address the question asked.

Comment: Optuna uses multi-thread only for parallel optimisation via the `n_jobs` argument of `study.optimize` method, where the number of processes is always 1. The multi-process-based optimisation can be done as answered in my first answer.